# Impossible seemingly simple CSS layout?

Tags: cross-browser, css

I've been fiddling with this the entire day and the closest I got is the following layout that works in Chrome (but not in Firefox).

1. Is it possible to do without the tables (and without js)?
2. Is it possible to make it cross-browser(tables or not but no js)?

To see the desired behavior, try changing the height of the window/display box.
Main points are:
 1. The layout is always at least the size of the window, but can expand past it if the content on the left pushes it.
 2. The scrollable area on the right always takes up the whole interior space, but doesn't expand it, meaning the height of the interior is determined by the left content (or size of window, whichever is larger).

Here is a JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/BNmJM/
And the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
td{
    vertical-align:top;
}
#wrapper{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-left:2px dashed black;
    border-right:2px dashed black;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="wrapper">
    <tr><td colspan=2 style="height:20px;">
        <div style="border-bottom:2px dashed black;height:20px;text-align:center;">header</div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="contentLeft" style="height:300px; width:100px;border:6px dashed green;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px;border-left:2px dashed black">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100px;overflow-y:scroll;">
                <div id="contentRight" style="height:500px; width:60px;border:6px dashed red;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2 style="height:20px;">
        <div style="border-top:2px dashed black;height:20px;text-align:center;">footer</div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes, this is definitely possible without tables and JS.

Comment: @TimMedora, any pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: start by eliminating the table. It really won't make things easier in the long run. I'm trying to create a simple Fiddle for you that does the trick, but no promises :)

Comment: I started with plain CSS but got stuck at getting the right column to be 100% height of the content box(between header and footer) and so switched to tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out using some box-sizing hacks, thanks to @Tim Medora for the help!
Unfortunately though, box-sizing doesn't work in IE7.
Here is the JSFiddle if anyone needs it: http://jsfiddle.net/vfMNw/
And the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
    }
    #container {
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    #header {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        background:#ff0;
        padding:10px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;  
        height:70px;
        width:100%;
    }
    #body {
        padding:10px;
        padding-bottom:60px;    /* Height of the footer */
    }
    #body1 {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #aaa;
        position: absolute;
        border-top: 70px solid black;
        top: 0;
        border-bottom: 50px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;  
        right: 0;
        width:100px;
    }
    #footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:50px;            /* Height of the footer */
        background:#6cf;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
    /* other non-essential CSS */
    #header p,
    #header h1 {
        margin:0;
        padding:10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    #footer p {
        margin:0;
        padding:10px; 
    }
    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #container {
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>How to keep footers at the bottom of the page (CSS demo)</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="body">h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br></div>
    <div id="body1">
        h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>h<br>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p><strong>Footer</strong> (always at the bottom). View more <a href="http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/-website-layouts">website layouts</a> and <a href="http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/-web-design">web design articles</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For older browser support, check the latest recommended polyfill: http://html5please.com/#box-sizing 

via http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

This actually seems to work in both the browsers (Chrome and Firefox). You can start from here and tweak accordingly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
td{
    vertical-align:top;
}
#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-left:2px dashed black;
    border-right:2px dashed black;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-menu" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; float: left;"></div>
        <div id="middle-content" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; float: left;"></div>
        <div id="right-scroll" style="width: 100px; height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid black; float: left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's missing header and footer. Once you add those in, keeping the scroll box desired height becomes impossible.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cSTzA/5/

Here's a start that works in Chrome and Firefox. It shows a layout that is always 100% with a fixed header and footer, and a scrolling right-hand pane.

Unfortunately it does not account for the left side growing but it should give you some ideas on how to proceed. It **is** possible but the complete solution isn't coming to me at the moment.

Here are several tricks that I use which may assist you in finding the complete solution:

- negative margins
- box-sizing
- a mix of absolute and relative positioning
- a mix of display styles (inline-block can be handy)

Comment: Thanks, already tried box sizing hacks and negative margins, along with absolute and relative positioning. Haven't tried inline-block yet but not sure how it could help with this.

Comment: @Roman - I may have to retract my earlier opinion about this being possible. I have tried several different approaches but I keep running into problems around 100% height. One of the approaches I'm using is well-documented here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks. It has some of the same limitations that we have already run into, but it's a better starting point than most.

Comment: FInally got it working with box-sizing hacks, thanks to you I didn't gie up :) http://jsfiddle.net/vfMNw/